# Does anyone know why my lines get blocked in preview (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Recently I have been experimenting with Unity Editor. I am trying to draw lines with handles for preview in Unity but somehow it gets blocked by grey area... and the lines aren't getting through to the right... Not sure what I did wrong, any help appreciated

```
Camera camera;
public override void OnPreviewGUI(Rect r, GUIStyle background)
{
    InitPreview();
    Vector3 zoom;
    m_PreviewDir = Drag2D(m_PreviewDir, r, out zoom);
    m_ScrollZoom += zoom;
    m_ScrollZoom.y = Mathf.Max(-33f, Mathf.Min(m_ScrollZoom.y, 44));
    if (Event.current.type != EventType.Repaint)
    {
        return;
    }

    m_PreviewUtility.BeginPreview(r, background);
    camera = m_PreviewUtility.camera;
    m_PreviewBounds.size = new Vector3(1, 1,1);
    float num = Mathf.Max(m_PreviewBounds.extents.magnitude, 0.0001f);
    float num2 = num * 3.8f;
    Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(-m_PreviewDir.y, -m_PreviewDir.x, 0f);
    Vector3 position = m_PreviewBounds.center - quaternion * (Vector3.forward * num2) * (1 + m_ScrollZoom.y * 0.02f);
    camera.transform.position = position;
    camera.transform.rotation = quaternion;
    camera.nearClipPlane = 0.1f;
    camera.farClipPlane = 1000.0f;
    camera.fieldOfView = 80;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is that grey area

Comment: Well it hits an opaque box so the part of the line inside the box is probably not rendered/the box is rendered on top of the line. I guess the essential part of your code might be hidden in `Drag2D`?

Comment: the place where red arrow points at

Comment: Isn't that C# and not UnityScript (a different programming language altogether)?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]